# Text document to screen

Tags: c#, xna, text-files, draw, readonly

Searching the internet for none console based text, read only, solutions has come up empty handed. I want to take from a text file and make it show on screen. I also want to learn how to use a scroll bar to scroll through the text if its to long (Y axis). If some one know were to direct me to learn about this or has an answer to the problem that I am having, I would be great full of your help.

I am using Microsoft visual C# 2010, XNA Windows Game (4.0) template.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @elyashiv It fixes the scroll bar problem but is it possible to tell me were the text from a .txt file can be added? It also is not in my references in the program witch is a problem. **EDIT:** This is for 2013, I have 2010, sorry.

Comment: notice the `other versions` menu at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, you should use a `TextBox`. You should set the property `Multiline` to true, and `ScrollBars` to `ScrollBars.Vertical`.

For reading the text file, use the following line:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(textFileLocation)
```

This will return a String with the contents of the file.